# Using boost::spirit to match words

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I want to create a parser that will match exactly two alphanumeric words from a string, such as:

```
message1 message2
```

and then save that into two variables of type std::string.

I've read [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421841/how-to-use-boostspirit-to-parse-a-sequence-of-words-into-a-vector) which seems to work for an endless amount of repetitions, which uses the following parser:

```
+qi::alnum % +qi::space
```

However when I try to do this:

```
 bool const result = qi::phrase_parse(
            input.begin(), input.end(),
            +qi::alnum >> +qi::alnum,
            +qi::space,
            words
    );
```

the `words` vector contains every single letter in a different string:

```
't'
'h'
'i'
's'
'i'
's'
```

This is extremely counter-intuitive, and I'm not sure as to why it's happening. Could someone please explain that?

Also, can I have two predefined strings to be populated instead of a std::vector?

**Final note:** I would like to avoid the **using** statement, as I would like to have every namespace clearly defined to help me understand how Spirit works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but the skipper ignores the whitespace before you can act on it.

Use `lexeme` to control the skipper:

```
bool const result = qi::phrase_parse(
        input.begin(), input.end(),
        qi::lexeme [+qi::alnum] >> qi::lexeme [+qi::alnum],
        qi::space,
        words
);
```

Note the skipper should be `qi::space` instead of `+qi::space`.

See also [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)